# How to format date using toString?

Tags: javascript, datetime

I have this date "Wednesday, 4th Apr 2018" format and I am trying to format this in "yyyy-MM-dd". It's working fine for all months but getting issue for April and august month. I am not getting what is the issue as it's working with other months
This is my code

```js
var Arrivaldte = Date.parse("Wednesday, 4th Apr 2018").toString('yyyy-MM-dd');
console.log(Arrivaldte);
```

Comment: There is no jQuery in your question - [date toString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toString) does not take a format. I think you meant [dateTimeFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat)

Comment: @phuzi - that is a VERY old post. There must be a better/newer post

Comment: i have already tried this

Comment: Also your parse does not accept that format. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse

Answer (score 0):

Using [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) docs as reference, your date string does not meet the standard [RFC2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-3.3) .

That `th` part should be removed. Example:

```js
var Arrivaldte = new Date("Wednesday, 4 Apr 2018").toString('yyyy-MM-dd');
console.log(Arrivaldte);
```

Alternatively, use `moment.js`:

```
moment("Wednesday, 4th Apr 2018")
```

But, be aware of this **deprecation warning**:

> Value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format. moment
> construction falls back to js Date(), which is not reliable across all
> browsers and versions. Non RFC2822/ISO date formats are discouraged
> and will be removed in an upcoming major release

Comment: Is there a way to  do it?

Comment: Use `moment.js`: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/

Comment: checked moment.js also but it returns invalid date always

Comment: Not for me, see my edited answer. Looks  like you have an incompatible browser.